# automatic reference counting preprocessor

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting

With ARC enabled, shouldn't the Preprocessor insert retain/release/autorelease calls?

When I let Xcode generate a preprocessed file, none of those show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC happens at a different level than the C preprocessor. At the time the C preprocessor runs, there isn't enough information to determine where to place the retain/release calls, because the preprocessor is just a textual substitution pass.

Comment: Is there a way to see the actual result? I have the feeling that my properties don't get released when they should...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know for sure. Perhaps you could ask the compiler to produce an assembly listing?